# ImportError: cannot import name 'fields' from 'django.db.models.fields'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

*I got the following error during creation of django serializer.*

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'fields' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/home/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)
```

and the **serializer.py** file is

```
from django.db.models.base import Model
from django.db.models.fields import fields, files
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Lead


#create serializers for Lead

class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = '__all__'
```

my current django version is 3.0.7.
what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: delete the second line `django.db.models.fields import fields, files` fields dose not have fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are trying to import `fields` or `files` as a matter of fact.

You are trying to import `fields` from `fields`. That will not work.

Also, the `class Meta` doesn't need you to import `fields` as it has access to this already. Remove the second line of code and give it a go, or if you need `files` for some other part of your code then just remove `fields`.